# Muffalo with blue wrap cover around it?

Tags: rimworld

When I was loading up a caravan, one of my muffalos was draped in this weird-looking blue drab. I don't see anything mentioned of it in the [Rimworld wiki](https://www.rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Muffalo), and despite having had dozens of muffalo caravans at this point, this is the first time I've ever seen this. Is this an easter egg, or is there some reasoning behind why the muffalo looks like this?

[image]

I thought this might have been the parka or tuque (hat) I loaded onto the caravan to sell, but even after dropping them from the caravan, the muffalo still looks like this.

Comment: Could this be from a mod? A quick look through the art source for the base game and expansions didn't turn up anything resembling your screenshot.

Comment: The only mods I have installed are https://i.imgur.com/DUBrWOG.png. None of them seem to add this texture as far as I can tell

Comment: Never seen it in my 100 mods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the **Vanilla Factions Expanded - Medieval** mod.

It's not really mentioned in the [description from the mod's Steam page](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2023513450), but digging through the mod's files on GitHub, I managed to turn up [this folder](https://github.com/AndroidQuazar/VanillaFactionsExpandedMedieval/tree/master/Textures/Things/Pawn/Animal/Muffalo) full of textures for muffalo packs.

A quick look at the East-facing texture shows that it looks the same as the outfit your muffalo is wearing (different color, but that just depends on the material used to make the item):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you've ever seen horses in winter in real life, it's the same thing.

It's essentially a blanket. It's part of their saddle.

Comment: I guess OP is questioning the origin of the drab from a game mechanics perspective, ie what caused it to appear there.